# Fighting Fury: weapon vs. implement usage. One, both or neither?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, monk

I want to create a Monk and like the Fighting Fury Utility power, but cannot figure out which attacks it would work with. Which keywords does it apply to? Implement, Weapon, another keyword? I want to be sure how it works and what all it works and doesn't work on to know if it's something I want to use.

### Background

I've plotted out what powers I'm going to add. I want a Monk who can attack more than one enemy per turn, not use a weapon (if he's holding anything, it will be a Ki focus), and all of my attack powers use implements. Some are close burst or blast attacks, while others are melee touch attacks. Will the Fighting Fury utility power give a bonus to any of these attack powers? Will it work on Stone Fist Fury of Blows, and/or will it work on basic attacks?

I want to understand clearly what keywords to look for on the powers to see if any of them can be boosted by Fighting Fury by looking for certain keywords in the powers descriptions. Because the unarmed strike can benefit from a ki focus, this has left me wondering if Fighting Fury can be combined with any attack that can use a ki focus. That's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @JohnW When you're asking about D&D 4e **please tag your question with the dnd-4e tag.** It is essential that you state what system you're using, or we can't know how to answer a question like this. You have been consistently leaving it off your D&D 4e questions. Save us the effort of having to add it for you, please.

Answer (score 1):

This power applies it's benefit to Unarmed melee attacks.

That means:

- Powers that have the property `melee`. This excludes the following attack power types: burst, blast, ranged, area. It only includes powers that explicitly say "melee [range]" (where range is: weapon, touch, 1, 2, etc).
- You must use the weapon "monk unarmed strike" or simply attack "unarmed" (stats for monk unarmed strike are in the class description, stats for simply attacking unarmed are +0 prof, 1d4 damage).
- Any additional details are irrelevant (ki focus, modifiers etc). the qualifiers are unarmed and melee.
- This is extra damage and thus only applies to powers that already do damage, even if they are melee and unarmed.

Comment: So can the Fighting Fury be combined with a Ki focus? For example: I use Fighting Fury on one turn, then use Strike the Avalanche on my next turn and do 2d10 + Dex Mod + STR Mod damage and +1 extra damage from my Ki focus, then for the following burst, if there had been damage (there isn't  a damage roll - just using as an example), I would only do damage equal to die rolls plus DEX Mod and Ki Focus damage, but no extra Fighting Fury STR Mod damage since the second attack is a Burst?

Comment: @JohnW yes to the first part, you're making the attack with the unarmed strike, the ki focus just provides enhancement bonuses here as if the unarmed strike were a magic weapon. To the second, it doesn't do any damage anyways so that doesn't matter. But no, even if it did damage it wouldn't apply the str mod because it's a burst.